# Configure multiple connection pools in playframework 2.6

Tags: scala, playframework, jdbc-pool

I was going over the documentation here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaDatabase#How-to-configure-several-data-sources. You can define multiple database connections:

```
# Orders database
db.orders.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.orders.url="jdbc:h2:mem:orders"

# Customers database
db.customers.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.customers.url="jdbc:h2:mem:customers"
```

that you can reference in the code using:

```
package controllers
import javax.inject.Inject

import play.api.mvc.{BaseController, ControllerComponents}
import play.api.db.{Database, NamedDatabase}

// inject "orders" database instead of "default"
class ScalaInjectNamed @Inject()(
  @NamedDatabase("orders") db: Database,
  val controllerComponents: ControllerComponents
) extends BaseController {
  // do whatever you need with the db
}
```

But how do you customize the connection pool for each connection ?

According to this document: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/SettingsJDBC you can specify the default config, database etc. the prototype settings for the connection pool and so on. How do I define the settings for *each* connection pool? Maybe one connection pool needs only one connection and the other one needs more.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using the hikaricp settings inside the database settings seems to do the trick:

```
db {
  mentions {
    driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
    url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mentions"
    password="***"
    username="play"
    hikaricp {
      maximumPoolSize = 2
      minimumIdle=2
    }

  }

  postgres {
    driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
    url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"
    password="***"
    username="postgres"
    hikaricp {
      maximumPoolSize = 9
      minimumIdle=9
    }
  }

}
```